# PyCharm throws "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute" when running tests for no reason

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

So, I have a Django-REST Framework project and one day it simply ceased being able to run the tests within PyCharm.

From the command line I can run them both using `paver` or the `manage.py` directly.

There was a time when that would happen when we didn't import the class' superclass at the top of the file, but that's not the case.

We have a `virtualenv` set locally and run the server from a vagrant box. I assured the virtual environment is loaded and that the project's Interpreter is using the afore mentioned virtual env.

No clue on what's the matter.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but my solution was different.

When I tried to run a test from PyCharm, the target path looked like this:

- tests.apps.an_app.models.a_model.ATestCase

But since ATest was a class inside a_model.py, the targ path should actually be:

- tests.apps.an_app.models.a_model:ATestCase

Changing the target in the test configuration worked.

Comment: The solution for me was quite similar.  The run-config was `api.opp.tests` and changing it to `opp.tests` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Given all the others paths were already covered:

- Import order
- Virtual Env created
- Project's Interpreter using the Virtual Env

The only thing that occurred to me was do run the following command within the vurtal env:

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

And it worked! In the end, someone had updated the requirements which weren't being met by my current virtual env. Screwing up with the paths/imports within PyCharm.