# Why does PyCharm fail to run unit tests?

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, pycharm, python-unittest

In my PyCharm (2016.3.3) project I have a package folder called 'tests', which holds some test modules (using `unittest`), e.g. 'test_A.py,' 'test_B.py.'

When I try to run the tests in one of these modules, or all tests in the entire 'tests' package, I get a `nose_helper.failure.Failure` due to `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_A'` (and same for the other test modules).

When I run the modules outside PyCharm they work without issue.

Does anyone know the reason, and how to solve this?

There are many similar questions here, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32615088), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20399046), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25575073), etc., but none of those solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea as to the exact cause, but in my PyCharm (2016.3.3) I was able to solve the issue by editing the run configuration:

From the menu bar select Run->Edit Configurations, then select your configuration, and in the "Configuration" tab under "Unittests" check "Inspect only subclasses of unittest.TestCase."

To make this default: Run -> Edit Configurations, then select Defaults->Python tests->Unittests, and again check the same box.

This answer was based on an [ancient PyCharm support post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205805169-PyCharm-1-5-1-error-when-running-test).

--edit--

This also happens (in PyCharm 2018.3) if a test module tries to import a non-existent class, e.g. (using django) `from myapp.models import MyModelA, MyModelB` where `MyModelB` does not exist. Fixing the import should resolve the issue, in this case.